# In Magento 2 i want to add the image in my custom module template file and the image i want to use is my company logo

Tags: image, magento-2.0.5

I tried this  with my  source but not work:

C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\magento\hello\view\adminhtml\templates\custom\logo.png

Comment: where you want to use that image

Comment: @PrashantValanda    template file in the custom view\adminhtml\templates\custom\form.phtml     i want to use it in form.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logo Image Width and Logo Image Height is fetched from Configuration Settings (Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> General -> Design -> Header).

Create a block class of your custom module for example (Magentotwo_LogoImage). Then injected object of Logo block in the constructor of your custom module’s block class. such as

```
<?php
namespace Magentotwo\LogoImage\Block;
class LogoImage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_logo;   

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $logo,
        array $data = []
    )
    {       
        $this->_logo = $logo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get logo image URL
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoSrc()
    {   
        return $this->_logo->getLogoSrc();
    }

    /**
     * Get logo text
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogoAlt()
    {   
        return $this->_logo->getLogoAlt();
    }

    /**
     * Get logo width
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLogoWidth()
    {   
        return $this->_logo->getLogoWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Get logo height
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getLogoHeight()
    {   
        return $this->_logo->getLogoHeight();
    }   
}
?>
```

Then you can easily use your function in template file such as

```
echo $block->getLogoSrc() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoAlt() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoWidth() . '<br />';
echo $block->getLogoHeight() . '<br />';
```